# How do I connect to an external database such as MySQL in PALM webOS

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, webos

I have a php code which i hosted on wampserver and a MySql database which I hosted in phpmyadmin. I have tried using Ajax request function which I wrote in the scene assistance file to call the PHP to access the database but its not working.

Comment: I think we'll need some more details.  Also, in what way is this related to webOS?

Comment: Are you trying to access it through the WebOS's browser? or are you trying to build an App?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am building a PALM webOS app that will enable users access from a PALM device to a MySQL database through VPN

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against connecting straight to the database from the device. Apps generally don't do that and there are very good reasons:

- A database server such as mysql isn't very good with handling multiple low-latency connections.
- You'll actually be allowing anybody access to the database and if you're using mysql's authentication for different users, that's not the best method. Will you be using SSL? because else the usersnames/passwords will be travelling through network pipes unfiltered exposing your server to multiple security risks.
- Updates are harder, caching is impossible.. etc.. many reasons.

What most apps do is actually create a server side application that will handle requests from the app in a RESTful way. So your app will query something like `http://myappdomain.com/objects/list` and return json or XML etc..

Comment: thanks alot, but i will be using SSL through VPN to authenticate users, Secondly, Please, how do I create a server side application?

Comment: Ok, so it's not a public application. That makes sense. A server-side application is typically built using software such as php (facebook), .net (stackoverflow) or ruby.. But there are many others. It depends on what language you like to program in and what sort of servers you have access to. It also depends on what you want the application to do.

Comment: thanks again, how do i get a http url from a mysql database for the ajax request?

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve a URL which is stored in a database? Because that's what you wrote. If you're asking how to get an HTTP url to connect to a mysql database with, it doesn't work that way. But I'm not sure I understood your question.